# image file is not moving to the path

Tags: image, laravel, file, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i am trying to implement update profile functionality, here's the form which is saving the data
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQJUz.jpg)

and here's the controller which is supposed to be saving image to the path [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjzQX.jpg)

there is relation in photo and user which is in the user class.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstName', 'lastName','userName' ,'email', 'password','photo_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
```

and here are the request files.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'firstName'=> 'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'userName' => 'required',
            'photo_id' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use files you should add:

```
'files' => true
```

to your form options:

```
{!! Form::model($user, [..., 'files' => true]) !!}
```

(in place of `...` you should put your other options - sorry I won't write text from image)

Comment: don't know how did i missed it:D 
thanks @Marnic Nabialek it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I am going to assume your problem is just about images not being moved to correct path.  In your controller try changing it like this

```
$file->move(yourdirectory .'/images/', $name);
```

Notice the . and / at the beginning of the directory. If you want the public path use public_path() function.